# What's the name of the mathematical structure with is an abstraction of things like linear Independence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

This is a terrible question, I know.  I can't remember the details for some reason, but I think (hope?) that anyone who's familiar with this object will immediately know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By going to [the see-also section of the wikipedia page for linear independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#See_also), I was reminded of the term ["matroid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid), which is almost certainly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  I was fairly sure it started with an "m" or "s" and ended with "-oid," but I wasn't able to search for that somehow!  I'll accept as soon as the ten-minute embargo is up.